# How to show a installation complete message after chrome extension installation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to open the chrome extension popup after the extension installation completes  automatically for one time only.

I am not sure whether it is implemented using extension popup.

I am having a Browser Action in my extension and i want to open that popup only one time after installation and i don't need any popup to show on click of extension icon(browser Action) later on.

In short i want the functionality of the popup that appears after installing Awesome Screenshot extension automatically for the first time only from the below link.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce

Please suggest me some way to implement this in my extension.

Comment: Awesome Screenshot extension does not open popup after installation. The popup `Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate has been added ...` is opened by chrome for every extension.

Comment: If you want to show some welcome information only one time after installation, you can consider using a tab instead of popup. `chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')})`

Comment: @Jacob Dam :  Yes it is by default and appears on installation from chrome webStore.